# Updating javascript Object, but it is updating all its instances, How can I prevent this

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have a query where when I am adding product then I am pushing it in the JS object for later use to checkout, but how would I prevent the same updating to other instances.

```
var cartObj = {};
  var tempProdList = '';
  
  /* cartObj = {
    productId: this.productId,
    prodName: this.productName,        
    pricebookId: this.pbId,
    prodPrice: this.productPrice,
    qty: this.noOfProducts,        
  }; */

  if(this.prodIdList.length == 0){
    this.noOfProducts = this.noOfProducts + 1;
    cartObj = {
      productId: this.productId,
      prodName: this.productName,        
      pricebookId: this.pbId,
      prodPrice: this.productPrice,
      qty: this.noOfProducts,        
    };
    this.prodList.push(cartObj);
    this.cart["cartItems"] = this.prodList;
  }else{
    for(var i = 0; i < this.prodIdList.length; i++){
      if(this.productId == this.prodIdList[i]){
        this.noOfProducts = this.noOfProducts + 1;
        cartObj = {
          productId: this.productId,
          prodName: this.productName,        
          pricebookId: this.pbId,
          prodPrice: this.productPrice,
          qty: this.noOfProducts,        
        };
        this.prodList.push(cartObj);
        this.cart["cartItems"] = this.prodList;
        break;
      }else{
        this.noOfProducts = this.noOfProducts + 1;
        cartObj = {
          productId: this.productId,
          prodName: this.productName,        
          pricebookId: this.pbId,
          prodPrice: this.productPrice,
          qty: this.noOfProducts,        
        };
        this.prodList.push(cartObj);
        this.cart["cartItems"] = this.prodList;
      }
    }
  }
  tempProdList = this.productId;
  this.prodIdList.push(tempProdList);
  console.log(this.cart);
```

So, what I am getting in the console is like this:

```
0: {pricebookId: "01u0x000006nTnxAAE", prodName: "Cyber Truck", prodPrice: 900, productId: "01t0x000005j51SAAQ", qty: 1}
1: {pricebookId: "01u0x000006nTnxAAs", prodName: "Roadster", prodPrice: 900, productId: "01t0x000005j51SAAQ", qty: 2}
2: {pricebookId: "01u0x000006nTnxAAw", prodName: "Cyber Truck", prodPrice: 900, productId: "01t0x000005j51SAAQ", qty: 3}
3: {pricebookId: "01u0x000006nTnxAde", prodName: "Roadster", prodPrice: 900, productId: "01t0x000005j51SAAQ", qty: 4}
```

Instead I want this:

```
0: {pricebookId: "01u0x000006nTnxAAE", prodName: "Cyber Truck", prodPrice: 900, productId: "01t0x000005j51SAAQ", qty: 2}
1: {pricebookId: "01u0x000006nTnxAAs", prodName: "Roadster", prodPrice: 900, productId: "01t0x000005j51SAAQ", qty: 2}
```

What should I do to prevent this

Comment: I think you've misidentified the problem here. All of your logical branches do the same thing (the `if` and the `else` are identical except a `break`!) I don't see how it's possible for this code to produce the given output unless `this.productName` and friends are dynamic properties.

Comment: So, what should I do, I mean I am trying to add the details dynamically in the JS object. So, if the same product found then it should only increase the number of product part and update the object of not then it should add on a new index

Comment: If you could [edit] your post to provide a Minimum Reproducible Example, you might get better answers. As I said, I cannot see how to reproduce the behavior you are describing with the code that is shown.

Comment: SFSE doesn't do hands-on troubleshooting in an org. We need _you_ to do the legwork to define the scope of the problem and write a post that includes the information we need to solve it. You can learn more at [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: My issue has been resolved, actually I have check closely in my html file and found that there was some mistake in that I have corrected that and it works fine. and thanks for all your help

Answer (score 2):

You are repeating yourself a lot in the code you just shared, which leaves a lot of margin for error.
you could simply iterate over your cart using a [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and add/update data based on the unique id, such as

```
this.cart.map( cartItem => { return {
    ...cartItem,
    // other props here that need updating if the item exists OR
    // create new prop, prodIdList
}})
```

Comment: it is showing this.cart.map is not a function, if I am trying to use it in this way. is it possible if you can elaborate your above answer. I mean in this way how I am going to make my cart and after that how would i iterate over this

Comment: with the above approach, you are basically "always" creating a new cart, and checking if an item needs change/update, as done above, you do not need the track decorator, you can also reduce/remove all those iterations, since they are quite repetitive, the linked documentation has plenty of examples on how to optimize your code

Comment: Thanku @glls will take your approach to optimize my code